# Is there a reason that withArgumentArrayElements(int) is not present on InvokeDynamic?

Tags: byte-buddy

`MethodCall` allows you to "spread" array arguments conveniently via the [`withArgumentArrayElements(int, int, int)`](https://javadoc.io/static/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.10.19/net/bytebuddy/implementation/MethodCall.html#withArgumentArrayElements-int-int-int-) method.

[`InvokeDynamic`](https://javadoc.io/static/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.10.19/net/bytebuddy/implementation/InvokeDynamic.html) features some analogous "with" methods, but not that one.

Is there a reason for this, or just the DSL hasn't been implemented here yet?

Answer (score 0):

It's simply not implemented, but a pull request adding this functionality would certainly be accepted.